# listView scroll remembering

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I got this listView wich is populated from SQL database via custom cursor adapter. When I click on an item, dialog shows up and asks for confirmation to delete that entry. If I select YES, it deletes item in the list and SQL entry also, and the setListView method I made reloads the list and scrolls back to the top of the list.
What I would like to do is that when I delete an item, the list should remember its position and show items that ware near that deleted item ( I don't want it to go back to top of the list ). How can I accomplish that?

Here is my code(onItemClick and setListView methods ):

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    final long arg3mod = arg3;

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(HistoryActivityMod.this);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Delete...");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this?");

    alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete);

    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

            db.delete(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, DbHelper.C_ID+"="+arg3mod, null);
            setListView();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Entry was deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();

}

public void setListView (){
    String[] columns= {DbHelper.C_ID, DbHelper.ROW1, DbHelper.ROW2, DbHelper.ROW3, DbHelper.ROW4, DbHelper.ROW5};

    Cursor cursor = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, "_id DESC");

    CustomCursorAdapter adapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),cursor, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public void setListView (){
    String[] columns= {DbHelper.C_ID, DbHelper.ROW1, DbHelper.ROW2, DbHelper.ROW3, DbHelper.ROW4, DbHelper.ROW5};

    Cursor cursor = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, "_id DESC");
    if(lv.getAdapter() == null) {
        CustomCursorAdapter adapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),cursor, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
        ((CustomCursorAdapter)lv.getAdapter()).changeCursor(cursor);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call `lv.setAdapter(adapter)`, this causes your list to reset to top. You can `lv.setAdapter(adapter)` only once and if your adapter is a `CursorAdapter` you can use its `changeCursor(cursor)` method to update its underlaying data.

So, in your `setListView()` method you can replace `lv.setAdapter(adapter)` with `adapter.changeCursor(cursor)`.

References:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor(android.database.Cursor)

Comment: I changed it, but listView doesn't get loaded. Where in the code should I call lv.setAdapter(adapter)?

Comment: After you create your adapter.